# SSAS: Weird error when Setting up Mining Structure

Tags: sql-server, ssas

This is very odd; I setup a simple mining structure, and when I go to process it, I get this error.  Doesn't point to the file the error is in, lists line and column as zero.  What would this be related to?

The ddl100_100:HoldoutMaxPercent element at line 184, column 38 (namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100) cannot appear under Envelope/Body/Execute/Command/Batch/Alter/ObjectDefinition/MiningStructure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug being worked on:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=509466&wa=wsignin1.0